# Android java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.List.stream use java 8 Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, android

Using java 8 Lambda Expressions
I am using Java JDK version jdk1.8.0_77 for both Android Studio.
I have also add jackOptions  in gradle
I have create simple list and add method  filter and sorted but after long time i have search but not any solution.

**Gradle file**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
    applicationId "com.mobisharnam.meme"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
```

**MainActivity**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<String> list =
            Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "c2", "c1");


   list.stream().
            filter(s -> s.startsWith("c")).
            sorted().forEach(s -> Log.d("TEST", s));

}
}
```

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection)
check out this answer...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are NOT chaining the stream methods properly, you can look below code:

```
list.stream().
            filter(s -> s.startsWith("c")).
            sorted().forEach(s -> Log.d("TEST", s));
```

Comment: You can look here, similar issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652633/collection-nosuchmethoderror-when-caling-stream-method